# AJAX error status code 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this code:

```
<a href="#">
    <i class="icon-heart" id="icon_heart" value="20"></i>
</a>
```

```js
var some_value = $("#icon_heart").attr("value"); 

$('[id=id_heart]').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=base_url(); ?>controller/save",
        type: "post",
        data: { some_value: some_value },
        success: function(dat){
            alert(dat);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```php
function save()
{
    $post = $this->input->post();
    $some_value = $post['some_value'];

    $dtl['some_field']  = $some_value;
    $dtl['date_insert'] = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
    $this->db->insert('resep_like',array_filter($dtl));

    $this->db->set('is_like', 'is_like+1',FALSE);
    $this->db->where('some_field', $some_value);
    $this->db->update('some_table');

    echo "success";
}
```

The insert and update queries is success, but the AJAX response returns `error: status code 500 internal server error`. Why can that be? It's successful but the result is error, and the `echo` from PHP is not displayed. How can i handle the response if it success but the AJAX `response` show error

Comment: A 500 error means the error is with your PHP code. Check the logs.

Comment: Check your `url` is it getting the `controller path`

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. You'll have much more info.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how can i check the logs in php sorry? can u provide me?

Comment: @SyarifHidayatullahLubis is `CSRF` protection enabled in config ?

Comment: @SyarifHidayatullahLubis try `console.log(dat)` instead of `alert(dat)`

Comment: @karanthakkar `CSRF` protection in config is set as `false`

Comment: @NarendraSisodia i have tried `console.log(dat)` then the response i got in `firebug` `console` is `success���������������������` and the HTML `success���` then i switch again to alert(dat) it not showing anything

Comment: type out your `console.log` response so that we can read it better, right now all we see is random characters

Comment: @CodeGodie that is my `console.log` response, it show what i see in `firebug` console. I see success and random character too

Comment: I use Chrome normally, but Firebug should have it as well. Look for the `Network` tab, and in the list look for `controller\save` POST you made, this should show you more information as well. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: @CodeGodie I have look at the `network` tab in `firebug` and i have no clue anything.. it makes me really desperate

Comment: do you want me to help you through Teamviewer?

Comment: guess not.. were you able to figure it out? update us

Comment: @CodeGodie hey CodeGodie.. sry not to mean that.. i was fall asleep yesterday and have some heavy work today.. i have solved this and my answer is in below. Thank you for your kindness care

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this the best answer or not..

I just solve this problem by change the `url: <?=base_url();?>controller/save` to `url: <?=base_url();?>save.php`

I point `url` of my ajax to my single file of php placed in root of document and not using the ci controller again to do the insert and update queries, then voila its work

If there a better method of this, please let me know it.

Thanks